# Set Edge Length In Vis.Js

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm trying to figure out if there is way to set the distance between edges using vis.js. I've played around with spring length and various physics variables, but can't seem to figure anything out. Ideally, I would like there to be an edge length setting that would determine the length of an edge. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Please show those attempts of yours to help others help you. Best regards